# Is there any tool to generate Object Graph on iOS app runtime?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode-instruments, object-graph

I know there are Class Model tools ([OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/), Doxygen) to generate Class model diagrams from the existing Xcode projects. But i'm looking for a tool which generates Object Graph on running iOS app in Simulator or Device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in

[ObjectGraph-Xcode](https://github.com/vampirewalk/ObjectGraph-Xcode)

[objc_dep](https://github.com/nst/objc_dep)

Comment: Sadly as of XCode 8 plugins like this are no longer supported. :-(

Comment: You can use SourceKit to generate some of the graph https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten

Comment: @JoeSteele objc_dep is just a python script, not a plugin

Comment: @bbjay -- true enough, but my comment was referencing ObjectGraph-Xcode which is a plugin based on that python script.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `KSHObjcUML` [here](https://github.com/kimsungwhee/KSHObjcUML).

It creates a nice interactive dependency graph to analyze in your browser.
[image]

Easiest to install with Alcatraz[here](http://alcatraz.io), a plugin package manager for Xcode 7. It is as easy to install plugins as it is to click a green button. And it does even support ObjectGraph-Xcode too.

[image]